# Spark SQL with Ignite

Tags: sql, apache-spark, ignite

I am trying to speed spark sql queries by introduce ignite as cache layer, by using IgniteRDD. From the example by ignite doc, it loads data from ignite cache to construct the RDD. But in our usecase the data size may too big to put into ignite memory, actually we just put the data in hbase, so is it possible to do:
1, construct igniteRDD by loading data from hbase 
2, Just use ignite to cache share rdd which is generated by spark sql to speed up spark sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from above three approaches, if you have flexibility to add another component, use Apache Phoenix. It supports integration with Spark SQL. You can check it on their official website. In this case you will not need Apache Ignite.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible usage scenarios.

First approach. If you run Ignite SQL queries from Spark using `igniteRdd.sql(...)` method then all the data must be stored in an Ignite cluster. Ignite SQL engine cannot query an underlying 3rd party persistence layer if not all the data is cached in memory. But if you enable [Ignite persistence](https://ignite.apache.org/features/persistence.html) and store all your data there instead of HBase then you can cache as much data as possible and run SQL safely since Ignite can query its own persistence.

Second approach is to use HBase as a [cache store](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store) (need to implement your own version since there's nothing out-of-the-box) and use Spark SQL queries instead of Ignite SQL because the latter requires us to cache all the data in RAM if Ignite persistence is not used.

Third approach is to try out [Ignite in-memory file system (IGFS)](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/in-memory-file-system) and [Hadoop accelerator](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/hadoop-accelerator). IGFS and the accelerator are deployed on top of HDFS. However, here you cannot use IgniteRDDs API because all the operations will go through this pipeline Spark->HBase->IGFS+Accelerator+HDFS.

If I were to choose I would go for the first approach.

Comment: Big thanks! Dose all these three approachs support embedded mode?

Comment: @Jerometan, yes, absolutely! However, Ignite developers discourage using the embedded mode unless Ignite nodes are pure clients: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7092